# New road bike comes with cryptic tag on the brake/shift lever

Tags: road-bike, brake-levers

I just got myself a *B'twin Triban 500*; this is my first road bike, and my second bike overall, so it's fair to assume I'm as newbie as can be.

The brake levers came with the following sticker, and I'm very intrigued by their meaning — especially since the brakes are a little out of reach from my ridiculously tiny hands, and this may be vaguely related.

[image: Shifters with three different angles, 0°, 4°, and 8°, corresponding to a movement of 0mm, 7.5mm, and 14mm respectively. Above the drawing of the levers are three schematics, showing some notches and knobs.]

Comment: Does the brake have a knob as well ? Does it resemble the setup described http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/avid-reg-mechanical-disc-adjustment

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. I've moved your indexing text to the image's alt tags. This is better for a number of reasons that I can't go into in such a confined space. I've also removed your "thank you" text. On all Stack Exchange sites, it is much preferred that you say "thank you" by by upvoting and accepting answers.

Comment: @Jontas: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I see the connection there.
jimirings: Ok, than…! hrr… :-)

Comment: From the tag / icon alone, I'd say it was warning of an 8% chance of an earthquake. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are referring to pad spacers. They essentially increase or decrease the amount of motion you have when moving the brake levers.

See page 16 of the following PDF for a better diagram:

[Shimano Brake Levers User Guide](http://si.shimano.com/php/download.php?file=pdf/dm/DM-ST0001-03-ENG.pdf)

Comment: This is entirely correct!  Thanks very much for that; so it does seem that I can reduce the distance from my fingers to the breaks using these spacers.  Now to find a place where I can buy them then!

Comment: They should have come with your bike, but if you haven't found them there, any decent LBS should have a bunch of them on hand

Comment: If you know how, check if they are present before buying.

Comment: Why are you commenting to your answer to your question?  Answering your own question is cool but praising your answer to your question in a comment is a bit far.

Comment: @Blam: Ahah, that's a nice one :-)  Admittedly, there is only one Blame, but as you can see, there are multiple Michaels.  I happen to be a umlaut-loaded one, however!

Comment: @andy256: There is indeed one in each brakes, but I would need the 8° ones if I ever want to reach those precious levers.  Thanks!

Comment: @Michaël OK cool but I am Blam.  But I am to blame for not seeing the difference.